# Discord.js send messages in order

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, discord, discord.js, embed

I have a discord bot that, on command, will send multiple messages to a channel. Some of the messages are images, and they always get sent last.

```
msg.channel.send({files: ["image.png"]});
for (var i in rules) {
    msg.channel.send({embed: rules[i]});
}
msg.channel.send({files: ["image2.png"]});
msg.channel.send({embed: embed1});
msg.channel.send({files: ["image3.png"]});
msg.channel.send({embed: embed2});
```

I want the messages to be sent in the order of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TextChannel.send()` returns a promise, so you can just use `async/await`

```js
// make sure your function is async
await msg.channel.send({files: ["image.png"]});
await msg.channel.send({files: ["image2.png"]});
await msg.channel.send({embed: embed1});
await msg.channel.send({files: ["image3.png"]});
await msg.channel.send({embed: embed2});
```

Comment: When I try this, it gives me this error:
`SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`

Comment: Well, you need to make the function asynchronous. Either `async function funcName() {...}` or `const funcName = async() => {...}` or similar, depending on how you are doing your functions

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using asynchronous functions, the messages will not sent by order of coding, but rather, they will be sent according to their processing time.

Since images are much bigger in size than text messages, they will be sent last in an asynchronous enviroment.

You need to use callback to turn those functions synchronous, but I recommend searching for a discord command that is synchronous by nature.

Comment: Ok, I will look into that.

Comment: You don't need to use callbacks, you can just it way more simply by using the `await` keyword. The `await` will not start the sending of the next message until the current one has finished sending

Comment: @Samathingamajig When I try this, it gives me this error: `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`

Comment: Well, you need to make the function asynchronous. Either `async function funcName() {...}` or `const funcName = async() => {...}` or similar, depending on how you are doing your functions